# What column type should I use for BigInteger mapping in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, oracle11g, hibernate-mapping

I'm using **Oracle XE** database and annotation driven mapping. What column type should I choose for `BigInteger` value mapping in Hibernate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you will see [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/mapping-types.html) it already mentioned

> big_decimal, big_integer
>
> Type mappings from java.math.BigDecimal and java.math.BigInteger to
>   NUMERIC (or Oracle NUMBER).

here is an example which i got from Hibernate community

Hibernate 3.1.1 with Oracle 10g and XE. The script of my Table sample is this:

```
CREATE sample (
sampa NUMBER,
sampb NUMBER(5),
sampc NUMBER(10),
sampd NUMBER(15,2),
sampe NUMBER(19,7)
);
```

and corresponding

```
<property name="sampa" column="sampa" type="java.math.BigInteger"/>
<property name="sampb" column="sampb" type="java.math.BigInteger"/>
<property name="sampc" column="sampc" type="java.math.BigInteger"/>
<property name="sampd" column="sampd" type="java.math.BigDecimal" precision="15" scale="2"/>
<property name="sampe" column="sampe" type="java.math.BigDecimal" precision="19" scale="7"/>
```